The Text inside TopAppBar is not clicking in Android compose app
I added a Text() inside the topAppBar right side.
TopAppBar having 3 elements left back button center title and right side clickable Text.
But the Texts clikable event not triggering. Same thing works if i put Text out side the TopAppBar.
How to achieve the clickable Text inside TopAppBar.
TopAppBar(backgroundColor = backgroundColor) {
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(5.dp),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Absolute.SpaceAround,
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
    ) {
        Image(

        )
        Text(

        )
        Text(
            text = "cancel",
            modifier = Modifier
                .wrapContentWidth()
                .padding(end = 16.dp)
                .clickable(
                    enabled = true,
                    onClick = {
                        //navigate to different screen
                    }
                ),
            textAlign = TextAlign.Right
        )
    }
}


Do you get any errors at all? It doesn't seem like this TopAppBar is set up correctly to me.

Here the issue is the Text in the TopAppBar is not clicking. Click event is not triggering. TopAppBar is loading correctly and  able to see the "Cancel" Text

@user7029573 Welcome to stackoverflow! If you found an answer useful, please mark it as accepted answer by clicking the checkmark at the left side of the answer

Please check out the documentation of TopAppBar to see which parameters it has and how to correctly use it. Also, a TextButton might be handy in your case.
You probably want something like this:
val context = LocalContext.current

Scaffold(
    topBar = {
        TopAppBar(
            navigationIcon = {
                 IconButton(
                     onClick = { 
                         Toast.makeText(context, "Button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show() 
                     }
                 ) {
                     Icon(imageVector = Icons.Filled.ArrowBack, contentDescription = "Back" )
                 }
            },
            title = {
                Text(
                    text = "App Title",
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .wrapContentWidth()
                        .padding(end = 16.dp)
                        .clickable(
                            onClick = {
                                Toast.makeText(context, "Title clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                            }
                        )
                )
            },
            actions = {
                TextButton(
                    onClick = {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Text clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                ) {
                    Text(text = "CANCEL")
                }
            }
        )
    }
) {
    Box(modifier = Modifier.padding(it)) {}
}

Output:

